# How to set the select element's value of a dynamically created form in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm working on two problems at once. Fortunately, I've narrowed them down so I can probably ask about the in one question with one plnkr example.

Here's the plnkr code I'm working on: http://plnkr.co/edit/qv1BX7WtpYhw5B92SuoC?p=preview

**What is it?**  It shows two cards, the top card is an example of using Dynamic Chips.

**What's wrong with it?** After the second chip is removed, that chip's information appears on the select box.

**What's happening?** When looking at the console output, I've logged the select's value (`<FormArray>this.updateProfileForm.controls["personNames"].value`).  What it shows is that when the first select is made, the value is blank.  The second time a value is selected, the value becomes what the first selection is.

After removing a chip, we see that the value is still that previously selected value.

**What am I trying to do?**  I'm trying to set the select's value to blank.  And I have not discovered or found the way to set the value.  If I try `<FormArray>this.updateProfileForm.controls["personNames"].value = '';`, it tells me this is not possible with a property that only has a getter.

*What is the proper method I should use to set the value to blank?*

-- Code block --

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<form [formGroup]="updateProfileForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
  <div id="names">
    <md-card>
      <md-toolbar color="primary">Dynamic Chips</md-toolbar>
        <md-card-content>
          <md-chip-list>
            <md-chip *ngFor="let person of people" (click)="removePerson($event)">{{person.name}} [X]</md-chip>
            <md-select id="names"
                       placeholder="Names"
                       formControlName="personNames"
                       (ngModelChange)="addPerson($event)">
                <md-option *ngFor="let name of names" value="{{name.code}}">
                    {{ name.name }}
                </md-option>
                <md-option disabled></md-option>
              </md-select>
          </md-chip-list>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</form>
```

--

```
// app.component.ts
  updateProfileForm: FormGroup;

   names = [
    {code: "F", name: "Frank"},
    {code: "G", name: "George"},
    {code: "H", name: "Henry"},
    {code: "I", name: "Inigo"},
    {code: "J", name: "Jose"},
    {code: "K", name: "Kevin"}
  ];

  removedNames = [];

  people: Person[] = [];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {      
      this.updateProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        personNames: ['', []]
      });
  }

  addPerson(selection): void {
    let selected = this.names.find(el => el.code === selection);

    this.people.push({name: selected.name});

    this.removedNames.push(selected);
    this.names.splice(this.names.findIndex(el => el === selected), 1);

    const control = <FormArray>this.updateProfileForm.controls["personNames"]
    console.log("Adding: control.value = ", control.value);

  }

  removePerson(chip) {
    // get name and remove the extra text
    let name = chip.target.innerText;
    name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(' '));

    // get the index of the name from the people array, then remove it from people (chips)
    let index = this.people.findIndex(el => el.name === name);
    this.people.splice(index, 1);

    // get the custom object from the removedNames array 
    let removedName = this.removedNames.find(el => el.name === name)
    // ... and add it back to names and sort
    this.names.push(removedName);
    this.names.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
      return 0;
    });

    // ... and remove it from removedNames
    this.removedNames.splice(this.removedNames.findIndex(el => el.name === name), 1);

    const control = <FormArray>this.updateProfileForm.controls["personNames"]
    console.log("Adding: control.value = ", control.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the answer was really simple.  Use "patchValue": https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#set-data

For the code above, I need to use

```
this.updateProfileForm.patchValue({
    personNames: ''
});
```

at the end of the removePerson() method. (Get rid of the last two lines, as well - `const control...` and `console.log`