# Why are the input and select boxes not filling in their values

Tags: angular

I have a form, created using nesting, that shows an input with a phone number and a select to select the type of phone number.  Initially, I have a set of values that I am trying to assign on creation of the formGroup.  But while the select boxes get their options, it does not select the predefined value. Nor does the input box receive it's predefined value.

In `app.component.ts:57`, I am taking my array of predefined values and parsing them individually and calling the `addPhoneForm` method.

The `addPhoneForm` method also utilizes the `initPhoneForm` method.  These, together, create the phone form that can be seen on line 33 of `app.component.html`.

I think the reason it is not being filled out is because I am also performing the following code within my `PhoneDetailComponent` constructor:

```
this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    phoneNumber: new FormControl(),
    phoneType: new FormControl()
})
```

But without that bit of code, I get an error stating that formGroup expects a FormGroup.

Here's the plnkr of what I'm working on. http://plnkr.co/edit/qv1BX7WtpYhw5B92SuoC?p=preview

-- code block --

-- phone-detail.component.ts

```
export class PhoneDetailComponent {

    phoneTypes: EnumProperty[] = [];
    phoneForm: FormGroup;

    @Input('group')
    @Output() rawChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();


    constructor(private phoneTypeService: PhoneTypeService,
                private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.getPhoneTypes();
      this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        phoneNumber: new FormControl(),
        phoneType: new FormControl()
      })
    }

    private getPhoneTypes() {
      this.phoneTypeService.get()
        .then(phoneTypes => {
          this.phoneTypes = phoneTypes;
        })
    }

}
```

--  app.component.html:31-36

```
  <div formArrayName="phones">
    <div *ngFor="let phone of updateProfileForm.controls.phones.controls; let i=index">
      <phone [group]="updateProfileForm.controls.phones.controls[i]"></phone>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a (click)="addPhoneForm()">+ Add another phone number</a>
```

-- app.component.ts (relevant parts only)

```
export class AppComponent {

  private version: any;
  updateProfileForm: FormGroup;

  phoneNumbers: PhoneModel[] = [
    { phoneNumber: "843-555-5849", type: "sms" },
    { phoneNumber: "756-555-7643", type: "home"},
    { phoneNumber: "395-555-9324", type: "tty" },
    { phoneNumber: "621-555-2690", type: "sms" }
  ]

  private phoneValidator = Validators.compose([
    Validators.minLength(7),
    Validators.maxLength(16),
    Validators.pattern(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/) ]);

  constructor(http: Http,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    // Display the currently used Material 2 version.
    this.version = http
      .get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/material2-builds/commits/HEAD')
      .map(res => res.json())

      this.updateProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        personNames: ['', []],
        phones: this.formBuilder.array([])
      });

      console.log("Loading phones");
      this.phoneNumbers.forEach(p => this.addPhoneForm(p));
  }

  private addPhoneForm(p?: PhoneModel) {
    if (!p) {
      p.phoneNumber = "";
      p.type = PHONE_TYPES[0];
    }

    const control = <FormArray>this.updateProfileForm.controls['phones'];
    const phnCtrl = this.initPhoneForm(p);

    console.log(p);

    control.push(phnCtrl);
  }

  private initPhoneForm(phoneModel: PhoneModel) {
    console.log(phoneModel);
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNumber: [ phoneModel.phoneNumber, this.phoneValidator ],
      phoneType: [ phoneModel.type, [] ]
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  First, in the PhoneDetailComponent class, we don't need the FormBuilder. It just confuses things. More especially, the reason it was there was because of a confusing error message that was so helpfully suggesting that I add it.  The problem was not the FormBuilder, but the property mismatches between what I was sending to the PDC class.

The working result is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qv1BX7WtpYhw5B92SuoC?p=preview

(This demo app also has an md-chip demo going. I have yet to solve the problem which is described in this question: [How to set the select element's value of a dynamically created form in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355725/how-to-set-the-select-elements-value-of-a-dynamically-created-form-in-angular2))

Here's how the PhoneDetailComponent class is supposed to look:

```
export class PhoneDetailComponent {

    @Input('group')
    phoneForm: FormGroup;
    phoneTypes: EnumProperty[];

    constructor(private phoneTypeService: PhoneTypeService) {
      this.getTypes();
    }

    getTypes() {
      this.phoneTypeService.get()
        .then(phoneTypes => {
          this.phoneTypes = phoneTypes;
        });
      }
}
```

Bad me... I didn't post the phone-detail.component.html relevant code.  But I may have had a mistake.  Here's what the html is supposed to look like.  Note that phoneTypes is part of the *ngFor of the option element. I had this correct.  What I may have had wrong were the formControlNames.

```
<div [formGroup]="phoneForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="Phone"
                   formControlName="phoneNumber"
                   (rawChange)="rawPhone=$event"
                   [attr.maxlength]="14"
            >
            <md-hint *ngIf="phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].hasError('required') && phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].touched"
                     class="text-danger">
                Phone number is required
            </md-hint>
            <md-hint *ngIf="phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].hasError('minlength') && phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].touched"
                    class="text-danger">
                Phone number is to be 10 numbers long
            </md-hint>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>Phone Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="phoneType">
            <option *ngFor="let type of phoneTypes"
                    value="{{type.code}}" 
                    title="{{type.description}}">
              {{type.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app.component.ts file is where I initialize the phone components. Make sure to match the formControlNames to what you set in the group.

```
  private addPhoneForm(p?: PhoneModel) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.updateProfileForm.controls['phones'];
    const phnCtrl = this.initPhoneForm(p);

    control.push(phnCtrl);
  }

  private initPhoneForm(phoneModel?: PhoneModel) {
    let pModel: PhoneModel = {
      phoneNumber: "",
      type: PHONE_TYPES[0]
    }

    if (phoneModel) {
      pModel = phoneModel;
    }

    return this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNumber: [ pModel.phoneNumber, this.phoneValidator ],
      phoneType: [ pModel.type ]
    });
  }
```